# Best practices - Local Node.js (*.env) to remote Azure app service (config settings)

Tags: azure, configuration, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-code

How are people transitioning between local development with .env files for Node.js to production deployment with Azure app service config settings?

Locally, I use a .env file for settings but on the cloud app service - I use service app settings. My deployemnt using the Azure app service extension deploys my .env file - which I don't want. The only way to stop it is to use a VSCode app setting which doesn't get saved to GitHub.

There has to be a better mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the zip deploy, VS Code *should* automatically add a `settings.json` file in your ".vscode" folder with a `appService.zipIgnorePattern`. That setting defines which items to ignore in the deploy. And it should be fine to check that into source control.